# migrate restful-authentication in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, restful-authentication

I want to migrate Rails 2 app to Rails 4. I have successfully migrated in Rails 3. Now I have a big problem with restful-authentication. It's not working for rails 4 so I need to migrate in devise but I don't want any changes with thousands of existing users.

Is it better to migrate in devise or is there some other alternative for restful-authentication?

Comment: Please provide some example-code, and what you've tried already. :)

Comment: I cleaned up the grammar, but there also needs to be more description of what has been tried and what the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

restful_authentication is no longer being maintained so I recommend migrating to an alternative like devise. With a bit of configuration you can set up devise to work with the passwords that have been encrypted through restful_authentication. There's guide on their github page on how to do it: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Migrate-from-restful_authentication-to-Devise